# ffmpeg: Force constant frame rate when encoding "timecode" video

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate

I want to generate a "timecode" video and need the output to be constant frame rate (CFR).  I've tried multiple approaches with the `fps` filter, `vsync` etc, but *MediaInfo* always reports that the output file is VFR.

How do I force constant frame rate output?

**Command:**

```
ffmpeg -loglevel info -y \
  -loop 1 \
  -i backgroundImage.png \
  -r 25 \
  -vsync cfr \
  -t 15 \
  -c:v libx264 -b:v 0.45M -threads 2 \
  -x264opts fps=25:keyint=25:min-keyint=25 -tune stillimage \
  -filter_complex \
  fps=fps=25,format=yuv420p,drawtext=fontfile='/fonts/NotoSans-Bold.ttf':x=30:y=400:fontcolor=white::fontsize=100:text='%{pts\\:localtime\\:1689994200}' \
  -sws_flags bilinear \
  -f mpegts -metadata service_name='Service01' -metadata service_name='MyService' \
  -muxrate 0.5M \
  outputTimecodeFile.ts
```

**MediaInfo says:**

```
Width                                    : 1280
Height                                   : 720
Pixel aspect ratio                       : 1.000
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : VFR
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Color space                              : YUV
```

**EDIT I**

Based on the comment by [1NN](https://superuser.com/users/714576/1nn) and [the related link](https://superuser.com/questions/879705/create-video-from-single-jpg-and-no-audio/880122#880122) I tried putting `-framerate` before the `-i` input (see below).

However, the result is the same: MediaInfo reports "Variable Frame Rate"...

```
ffmpeg -loglevel info -y \
  -loop 1 \
  -framerate 25 \
  -i backgroundImage.png \
  -r 25 \
  -t 15 \
  -c:v libx264 -b:v 0.45M -threads 2 -x264opts keyint=25:min-keyint=25 -tune stillimage \
  -filter_complex \
  format=yuv420p,drawtext=fontfile='fonts/NotoSans-Bold.ttf':x=30:y=400:fontcolor=white::fontsize=100:text='%{pts\\:localtime\\:1689994200}' \
  -sws_flags bilinear \
  -f mpegts -metadata service_name='Service01' -metadata service_name='myService' \
  -muxrate 0.5M \
  timecodeFile.ts
```

**EDIT II**

According to [this MediaInfo bug report](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfo/issues/576), MediaInfo uses the `fixed_frame_rate_flag` within the H264 stream to decide if a stream is variable or fixed.

However, ffmpeg is creating the stream with `fixed_frame_rate_flag` set to zero (confirmed using `ffmpeg -i inputFile.ts -c:v copy -bsf:v trace_headers -f null - 2>&1 | grep fixed_frame_rate`

Supposedly I can set that flag using the bitstream filters. I tried adding `-bsf:v h264_metadata=fixed_frame_rate_flag=1` to the command but I get a lot of errors:

```
Error applying bitstream filters to an output packet for stream #0:0.
[h264_metadata @ 0x1887380] PPS id 0 not available.
[h264_metadata @ 0x1887380] Failed to write unit 0 (type 1).
[h264_metadata @ 0x1887380] Failed to write access unit into packet.
```

**References:**

- [Force ffmpeg to produce constant frame rate](https://superuser.com/questions/1718892/force-ffmpeg-to-produce-constant-frame-rate)
- [FFMPEG / libx264: How to specify a variable frame rate but with a maximum?](https://superuser.com/questions/908295/ffmpeg-libx264-how-to-specify-a-variable-frame-rate-but-with-a-maximum)
- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: You have only one image as input. An image does not have any framerate, so you'll need to specify `-framerate 25` befor the `- i` parameter. `filter_complex`will not define the fps of your output ! See even: https://superuser.com/a/880122/714576

Comment: VBR is variable **bit** rate. This says nothing about the **frame** rate.

Comment: DoxyLover: thanks, fixed the typo. Should be "VFR"